# react - onclick using event without using arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a link to return home and within that there is a button to remove an item from an array. To prevent the link to redirect to the home screen and to just remove the item from the array I am need to use `ev.preventDefault()`.

Is it possible to pass an `ev` to a react method without using an arrow function in the `render` method? From my research and specifically [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350988/react-passing-parameter-via-onclick-event-using-es6-syntax) it appears that the following is the only way to do so.

I am concerned that the arrow function causes a re-render every time, since new function is created on each render.

```
removeItem(label, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.removeItem(label.id);
}


render () {
    const { label } = this.props;
    return (
      <Link to'/'>
        <span>Go Home</span>
        <span onClick={(e) => this.removeItem(label, e) }> Click me <span>
      </Link>
    );
}
```

Comment: You could just remove the label parameter and get `label` from `this.props`directly. Then you could just have `onClick={this.removeItem}`

Comment: Although, creating a new function on every render, probably isn't all that expensive :)

Comment: good spot, but will I be able to still use `e.preventDefault`?

Comment: Yeah you will :) Does this answer your question? I can make a full answer out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just remove the label parameter and get label from this.props directly. Refactor your app like this:

```
removeItem(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.props.removeItem(this.props.label.id);
}


render () {
    const { label } = this.props;
    return (
      <Link to'/'>
        <span>Go Home</span>
        <span onClick={this.removeItem}> Click me <span>
      </Link>
    );
}
```

This way, React will automatically pass the click event to your `removeItem` method.

Although, it should be said, that creating a new function on every render, probably isn't all that expensive.

Answer (score 0):

In the light of avoiding to re-create the function you could extract the parameters into the class props. Here are some [examples](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)

For example this will create a new function all the time.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <li key={item.id} onClick={this.props.onItemClick.bind(null, item.id)}>
            ...
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Now it will not re-create the functions on re-rendering.

```
var List = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item =>
          <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} onItemClick={this.props.onItemClick} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});

var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li onClick={this._onClick}>
        ...
      </li>
    );
  },
  _onClick() {
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.item.id);
  }
});
```

Here is some SO explanation [React js onClick can't pass value to method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)