# Pass param when using bind this with constructor in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JSX

```
<a onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this)}/></a>
```

Function

```
handleSave(param){

}
```

How to pass param from Jsx to my handleSave function? I did not set everything in state. The a tag is a children of another component.

Comment: Use `this.handleSave.bind(this, param)` or If you want you can use ES6 arrow function. `onClick={() => handleSave(param)}` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350988/react-passing-parameter-via-onclick-event-using-es6-syntax) answer on how to use arrow functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js onClick can't pass value to method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810914/react-js-onclick-cant-pass-value-to-method)

Answer (score 1):

You can set arguments while calling `bind`

```
class App extends Component {
  handleClick(name){
    alert(this.props.appName + " : " + name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.appName)} >Click Here</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to bind functions on JSX elements, you should bind them on the constructor, that way, it wont generate a function on every render:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this, this.props.appName);
  }
  handleClick(name){
    alert(this.props.appName + " : " + name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <a onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the name of your function, I presume you would like to pass a parameter based on the event, so if that's the case you can do:

```
<a onClick={(e) => this.handleSave(e.target.value) }/></a>
```

Arrow functions preserve the context of `this`, so you don't have to use bind.

Comment: you don't bind this because u used arrow function. Nothing wrong with using bind this in my case.

Comment: That's why I said "I presume you would like to pass a parameter based on the event". If you shared more information about the parameter you wish to pass, the answers would be more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {
    handleSave(param){
        // doing what you need with your (param)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <a onClick={this.handleSave.bind(this, param)} >Click Here</a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).