# React arrow function produced different debugging experience

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently working on a react UI project, and involves lots of debugging with browsers. The strange thing is that when I do not use arrow function on button click event, the browser debugger shows this.state as undefined when mouse over it. When I use arrow function

> {() => this.alert()}

the debugger console shows the correct state when mouse over and both these logging correct output when I do console.log(). Also I tested this behavior in Chrome and it is same as FF.

Any one has any idea will be much appreciated, since this brings really big issue when debugging without seeing the state, and it is not realistic to console.log for every state change.

[Could not show this.state when mouse over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC4GD.png)

[Can show this.state when mouse over](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKr7T.png)

Comment: Do this onClick={() => this.alert} instead of onClick={this.alert} when you use arrow functions

Comment: @Think-Twice, onClick={() => this.alert} will not work, either you use onClient={() => this.alert()}, or totally no bracket

Comment: Hoo okey got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that when you do:

```
somehandler = () => { ... }
```

in your component, it's *already bound* to the component instance, i.e. `this = your component instance`, so you don't need to do `onClick={() => this.somehandler() }`, which binds it *yet again* to the component instance.

Stick to the former and you'll be good to go!

**Edit:** I now realize that it's actually `onClick={this.somehandler}` that's causing you console.log grief. It may be related to either how the Babel transform or the Dev Tools are implemented... You can try a classic bind like this, to see if it helps:

```
constructor() {
  this.somehandler = this.somehandler.bind(this);
} 

somehandler() {
   // ....
}

render() {
  return <button onClick={this.somehandler}>...</button>
}
```

Comment: constructor() { this.alert = this.alert.bind(this); }  works, and the debugger console shows correct message. I also believe it is due to Babel, but can't not prove it

Comment: And i found it is recommended NOT use arrow function in render, because it will create a function wrapper. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350988/react-passing-parameter-via-onclick-event-using-es6-syntax/34351087

Comment: yes, it's true that you should avoid anonymous (arrow) functions as handlers.